# Getting the linux time since power on

Tags: python-3.x, linux, discord.py

I've got

```
time = os.popen("tuptime").readline()
```

and the output should be something like:

```
System startups:        1   since   21:32:26 01.05.2020
System shutdowns:       0 ok   -   0 bad
System uptime:          100.0%   -   1 day, 16 hours, 49 minutes, 41 seconds
System downtime:        0.0%   -   0 seconds
System life:            1 day, 16 hours, 49 minutes, 41 seconds

Largest uptime:         1 day, 16 hours, 49 minutes, 41 seconds   from   21:32:26 01.05.2020
Shortest uptime:        1 day, 16 hours, 49 minutes, 41 seconds   from   21:32:26 01.05.2020
Average uptime:         1 day, 16 hours, 49 minutes, 41 seconds

Largest downtime:       0 seconds
Shortest downtime:      0 seconds
Average downtime:       0 seconds

Current uptime:         1 day, 16 hours, 49 minutes, 41 seconds   since   21:32:26 01.05.2020
```

how can i get and print out the "System life"?

Comment: you can use `"tuptime| grep -i 'system life'"` in the cmd instead of `tuptime`

Comment: terminal return: `grep: life: There is no such file or directory`

Comment: "tuptime| grep -i 'system life'"

Comment: yeah, work, thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `"tuptime| grep -i 'system life'"` in the cmd instead of `"tuptime"`